# swipe recognizer get only one direction recognized

Tags: swift

swipegesturerecognizer recognize only the right direction. 
left, up or down did not recognized and not even calls the selector

am using swift 5 Xcode 10.3

```
func setupUserInteraction(){
    self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handelSwipe)))
}

@objc func handelSwipe(g: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    if g.direction == .right {
        print("Swipe Right")
    }

    if g.direction == .left {
        print("Swipe Left")
    }
}
```

this code above shows "swipe right" when i swipe right

nothing when swipe left

Comment: Try reading the docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiswipegesturerecognizer/1619178-direction A swipe gesture recognizer has only one direction, and unless you set it, it is `.right`. If you want to recognize two directions you need to recognizers.

Answer (score 0):

thanks alot

it works by adding two swipe gesture recognizers 
i defined the direction by each then attach them to the view 
each have separated selector handler

```
func setupUserInteraction(){
    self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipeRight))
    swipeRight.direction = .right
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

    let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipeLeft))
    swipeLeft.direction = .left
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)
}

@objc func handleSwipeRight(){
    print("Swipe Right")
}

@objc func handleSwipeLeft(){
    print("Swipe Left")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Adding onto [@matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341994/matt), you can only have one direction on a swipe recognizer, while the default is 'right'. You can/should set the direction manually.

Depending on your use case, you should also look into [UIPanGestureRecognizers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipangesturerecognizer) as it would support multidirectional flows, but requires more setup.